# Missing Authorization in Google form submission

Tags: forms, authorization, google-apps

I have google apps of form, when response save in spreadsheet, it activate a script to send an email to a user. After running 4 months, today I got an error message through script response:

```
Details:
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
11/10/16 10:49 AM   formSubmitReply Authorization is required to perform that action.   formSubmit  11/10/16 10:49 AM
```

I checked "Connected apps & sites" of "sign-in & security" of "My Account" in google. It registers 7 my apps but not the error apps.

So, I want to ask how I can activate the missing apps in authorization list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this one yesterday. I opened the faulty script in the script editor and executed it with the Run (play button) command. Don't forget to choose the function name in the drop down list on the right or it will be greyed out.
Then it asked for permissions, after granted everything was alright again.